# Why Choose Talmud Bavli For The Daily Study

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, daf-yomi

As we know it is a big custom to learn a daf of Talmud Bavli a day (Dafyomi).

My question is why did they choose to pick Talmud Bavli. There are so many other Subjects that could actually affect your day to day life.

Comment: (I asked a question recently Why Do Yeshivos Learn Talmud Bavli so extensively (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40916/why-do-yeshivos-learn-talmud-bavli-so-extensively) this question runs on similiar lines with my other question but very different because this question is not talking about yeshiva where they teach you how to learn but here it is much different.

Comment: What makes us special is the Talmud since it is a mesora passed down and virtually every halacha comes from it and the Talmud explains Tanach and gives us insight to everything about are religion ,Tosfos writes that the Talmud has a mix of everything and it should be the main limud.

Comment: It also depends on how much time one has to learn,if they have alot of time Talmud Bavli should be studied ,but if one dies not have time to study a long time then poskim(halacha) should be studied ,see Shach 246:5

Comment: "if they have alot of time Talmud Bavli should be studied" why?

Comment: because it is the source for everything ,see the Yam Shel Shlomo (Rav Shlomo Luria) who explains the importance of learning talmud

Comment: Actually, I saw somewhere that learning Mishna Yomit is more valuable, because not every masechta has Gemarah, so you are "missing" some topics.

Comment: @DanF, how long would that take?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - From www.mishnayomit.com - "Join many around the world learning just 2 mishnayot a day and finish Shas in under 6 years." I haven't browsed their site myself, yet. This is one of several sites that are related to Mishnah Yomit. I wouldn't doubt that there is a Yerushalmi Yomi, as well, but haven't found it, yet. Think of it this way - if someone hadn't thought of putting Pirkei Avot in the siddur, and you relied on just Daf Yomi, you might have missed out on the beauty of Pirkei Avot. Recently, I learned most of Masechet Bikurim. Learn that & you appreciate Israel more!

Comment: @DanF, according to the wiki for daf-yomi, there is a Yerushalmi yomi.

Comment: So why is DafYomi so much more popular than MishnaYomi I am guessing because more rabbonim said to learn DafYomi if that is true then Why?
 @sam can you say in kitzur his reason 
I also saw KitzurYomi, Shulchan Aruch Harav Yomi, Mishneh Burah Yomi, Hayom Yom, RambamYomi (Sefer Hamitzvos, Perek Echad and Shlosha Prakim) Chumash with Rashi Daily Alyiah and TanyaYomi (http://kitzur365.org/ , www.kitzuryomi.org) (http://orachchaim.com/) (http://learnshulchanaruch.info/) (http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/default_cdo/jewish/Daily-Study.htm)

Comment: One cannot understand the Mishna without the Talmud,the Mishna was written down in a very concise way so Israel would not forget the oral law,but the Talmud itself is the discussion,explanation and expounding of the Mishna

Comment: All the schools I know of teach Mishnayos Learning (around) 20-40 Prakim of Mishnyaos before they stop and learn Talmud. So far it seems that people should first learn the whole entire mishnyaos and then start the talmud but I feel like that is not happening in most cases unless I am wrong in my point of saying that you should learn the full Mishnayeos then start with Taldmud but so far it has yet to be wrong

Comment: And my question still stands. Why is DafYomi the most famous (and through that may be being the best) Daily study out of all of the other Daily Study

Comment: i think simply because it gives more "chiyus" (life) than any other type of learning. others have told me the same thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this historical question will turn out to have been **heavily** influenced by the answer to your other historical question about why so much emphasis is placed on G'mara learning. In fact, you show that you believe they are closely related as well by using the insufficient study of Mishna _in school_ as part of your argument regarding learning G'mara _on one's own time_.

Comment: I believe you are correct in implying that the volume of Mishna taught in school is not meant to be comprehensive, but it is probably designed to give the student the tools to continue studying Mishna independently. Daf yomi, on the other hand, is something usually engaged in by adults, presumed all the more competent in their independent learning after getting Mishna under their belts in their youth.

Answer (score 2):

In the olden days - as stated in Pirkei Avoth בן חמש למקרא - one would only learn Shas (Talmud Bavli) after becoming proficient in Chumash and Mishna.

One would then concentrate on Shas as it's the basis for Halacho.

Besides, it's really difficult to properly understand Rambam, Tur and Shulchan Aruch (the 3 "off the page" pillars of Halacha) without having learned the relevant pieces on Shas. All the more so if one tries the Rif, Ran and Rosh who wrote "on the page".

So somebody who wants to live a meaningful - and Halachic - Torah life needs to become proficient in the DNA of Halacha - i.e. become proficient at Talmud Bavli.

Obviously, if one simply learns the Daily Daf and doesn't delve all the way into the practical applications of what one has learned, then one is simply "playing along" while missing the whole point of learning. (True for any learning program.)

To summarize:  The point of the Daf Yomi program was two-fold:

1. Ensure all Jews are learning the same Daf - thus making it easier from travelers to continue learning wherever they land.
2. Ensure everybody can learn the entire Shas in a sensible time frame; thereby ensuring they cover all practical aspects of Jewish life every 7 years.

It was self understood that after/while learning the Daf one would continue on to its practical application.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on this point "Besides, it's really difficult to properly understand Rambam, Tur and Shulchan Aruch (the 3 "off the page" pillars of Halacha) without having learned the relevant pieces on Shas. All the more so if one tries the Rif, Ran and Rosh who wrote "on the page". 1. I feel that Rambam Mishneh Torah, Shulchan Aruch Harav, Mishnayos, Mishna Berua, Kitzur. Are all much easier than Talmud Bavli.

Comment: "Obviously, if one simply learns the Daily Daf and doesn't delve all the way into the practical applications of what one has learned, then one is simply "playing along" while missing the whole point of learning. (True for any learning program.)"

How are you Supposed to Delve Deeply into a Daf of Gemorah each day? It will take very long. DafYomi is more of a girsa Gemorah Daily.

Comment: "So somebody who wants to live a meaningful - and Halachic - Torah life needs to become proficient in the DNA of Halacha"- Why can't you accomplish that with lets say KitzurYomi.

Comment: @user613 - 1. because you are then limited to what is said--and any action slightly "different" (like the 100's asked on this site or to any Rabbi) you'll have no idea what to do and 2. because you don't understand what and why the halacha is the way it is; e.g. are you doing a d'Oraitha, a d'Rabanan or a Minhag. E.g. How to behave in less than optimal situations - emergencies, pressed for time, unwell, etc. There's more but this is a taste.

Comment: @user613 - of course "Rambam Mishneh Torah, Shulchan Aruch Harav, Mishnayos, Mishna Berua, Kitzur. Are all much easier than Talmud Bavli" because they've given you conclusions - but without the background you're kind of stuck if you want to deal with cases not clearly spelled out.

Comment: @user613: "DafYomi is more of a girsa Gemorah Daily." True. " How are you Supposed to Delve Deeply into a Daf of Gemorah each day? It will take very long" - see the OP who clearly has time to learn and is wondering how to use that time properly. Obvioulsy if you only have 45 minutes / day to learn then most of it should be practical Halacha (and some Mussar to  help you find more time.)

Comment: But even if you have 2 hours you won't be able to go into a daf very deep and remember what you learnt after. So the question becomes 1. most dafyomi classes I see are 45-60 minutes so it looks like that is not the case that you should delve deeply into a daf but on the other hand who established and motivated this project because who was this project pointed at? If it was regular baal habatim then most baal habatim are not spending the time they need. And also even if you had enough time to delve into a daf why don't spend that time learning Shulchan Aruch Harav.

Comment: @user613 - if you seriously want to understand the basis of the Shulchan Aruch Harav (and which specific cases he's referring to ) you will eventually land up at the Gemara; so it makes sense to start at the Gemara and then see how its conclusion matches the Shulchan Aruch Harav. Unless of course, you're in need of the basics for your everyday living - then you urgently need to first learn the Shulchan Aruch Harav - or similar, so that you know how to behave as a good Yid.

Comment: (Side point: there is a sefer Beis Yosef which says extensively the reasoning etc.) "And also even if you had enough time to delve into a daf why don't spend that time learning Shulchan Aruch Harav." what I meant was 1. what makes Gemorah better than Shulchan Aruch Harav (or any other yomi) to learn everyday? 2. I was not saying they should go deep I was saying if so then they should spend the TIME.

Comment: 3. Halacha in general or any other learning yomi. (like I said above) if this schedule was pointed at baal habatim they 1. can't spend enough time on it 2. even if they did why spend time on talmud 3. most baal habatim do not know all halachos

Answer (score 2):

In the introduction to the Shulchan Aruch, the Mechaber, HaRav HaGaon Yosef Caro Z"tzl explained that his work was meant to be learned over a period of 30 days. (lol)

Thus, from a stand point such as that, the basic source of psak halacha shouldn't take more than a month or so to actually take in at least on a basic level.

The Talmud on the other hand can be learned with extreme depth (i.e. machlokes Rishonim, points by Acharonim, psak halacha) and forms the cornerstone of not only our legal code and explanations on how to perform the commandments, but also is full of midrashic materials that strongly contribute to our hashkafic (and even mystical) understandings of the realities of existence. Hence, the Talmud is something that is far beyond simple psak halacha (something that as mentioned above was indeed meant to be completed quickly).

This is an answer based upon a pshat type of fold, the great mystical significance of learning the Talmud as brought down in the writings of Rabbi Nachman from Breslov, and other Mekuballim is also something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [JewishHistory.org](http://www.jewishhistory.org/daf-yomi/) (which says its information is based on the work of [R. Berel Wein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berel_Wein)):

> [Rabbi Meir Shapiro, the originator of the idea] saw daf yomi as a tremendously necessary unifying factor among the Jewish people. He said that if you look at a page of the Talmud, you see the words of the greatest Jewish minds covering the entire spectrum of Jewish life and history: There were Jews from the Land of Israel and Babylon; from France (e.g. Rashi) and Germany (the Baalei Tosafos); and in the back of the Talmud there was Rabbeinu Asher, “the Rosh,” from Spain, the Maharsham from Poland and the Maharam from Lithuania. He said that a page of the Talmud is the most universal and unifying fact in Jewish history because everyone great from every place in the world in history are all gathered in a single place.