# Why does the yeshiva system focus mainly on the study of the talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, yeshiva-school

It seems, almost across the board, that most yeshivas spent the majority of their time studying the talmud while allocating very little (if any) time towards the study of other critical judaic texts such as halacha/tanach/etc.

I do see how studying the talmud can be a more engaging endeavor due to the challenge and back and forth style of the gemara. **But it doesn't seem to justify having students that spent years upon years studying "torah" that come out of yeshiva being ignorant in large areas of halacha and other jewish texts.**

What are the sources behind the current yeshivah learning style and what are the reasons behind it?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40916/why-do-yeshivos-learn-talmud-bavli-so-extensively